# Блокирование основного потока при выполнении очереди

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, kivy

Не могу разобраться с потоками, почему Диалоговое окно показывается только после выполнения потоков получающих данные о погоде?

```
class LoadBox(Popup):
    pop_up_text = ObjectProperty()
    pop_up_progress_bar = ObjectProperty()

    def run(self):
        pass

    def update_pop_up_text(self, p_message):
        self.pop_up_text.text = p_message

    def update_pop_up_progress_bar(self, p_value):
        self.pop_up_progress_bar.value += p_value

        if self.pop_up_progress_bar.value>= 100: 
            self.dismiss()
            return False


class TestApp(App):

    def show_popup(self, message):
        self.pop_up = Factory.LoadBox()
        self.pop_up.update_pop_up_text(message)
        self.pop_up.update_pop_up_progress_bar(5)
        self.pop_up.open()

    def process_button_click(self):
        # Создаем диалоговое окно
        self.show_popup('Get weather...')

        # Получаем данные
        self.refresh_weather()

    def refresh_weather(self):
        # Инициализируем очередь
        queue = Queue()

        days = ["yesterday",
                "today",
                "tomorow"]

        # Запускаем очередь
        for i in range(3):
            t = Weather(queue)
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()

        # Даем очереди нужные нам данные
        for day in days:
            queue.put(day)
            self.pop_up.update_pop_up_progress_bar(10)

        # Ждем завершения работы очереди
        queue.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

В основе работы всех библиотек графического интерфейса лежит один принцип - при старте приложения запускается бесконечный цикл, который на каждой итерации достаёт событие интерфейса из очереди и выполняет для него обработчик. Пока обработчик не завершится, цикл не продолжится и никакие другие события обработаны не будут. В том числе не будут обработаны события на перерисовку окна, приложение зависнет. К тому же подавляющее большинство GUI-библиотек не являются потокобезопасными.

Comment: А как тогда реализуют progressbar'ы в приложениях? Подскажете путь где искать?

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров обычно, GUI-библиотеки предоставляют специальные механизмы для работы с потоками, а некоторые задачи можно реализовать и без использования многопоточности. С Kivy я не работал, так что конкретного решения не подскажу.